# How to convert graphical images to ASCII art?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, image-processing

I want a custom image in my terminal made of characters, is there a program I can use?

Specifically, the gear within my school's robotics
[logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ta2.jpg).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One app you can try `jp2a` for jpg to ascii for terminal windows.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install jp2a
```

Then just run `jp2a filename.jpg`

```
~$ jp2a 1Fy7Yz2.jpg 

.dKKKKKl.....dKK000000OOOOkkkxxxxddoooooolloddxxxkO00k....................
'0KKKK0..'...oKKK000000OOOOOkkxxxdddooooollodxxxxkO00O....................
dKKKK0,....'.:KKKKK0000000OOOOkkxxxddddoooooxxxxkOO00O'...................
0KXK0.  ........'',,,,,;;;;;;;;;;;,,,'''''.''''....'';;...................
O0O0o............                                 ...'l...................
0K0kkkxxxdol:.    .,:;;.....           .   ... .   .......................
d000kkOKKKKKKk.  .dO000klooc;... .  .':::ccood;... c,.....................
..oOkdx0KKK0KKx.  ,,od.l'xdl.  ':ldkkkkxxdxO0KXo.  cc.....................
. :kxodk00O;0K0k,   'l,,.;;cok00OOkxxxkkxxxk0Kkkk:,,k.....................
..lxdookkOl.'OKKOd;,;coxO0000OkdoodkOOOkxddk0KkodOxdk.....................
loldccdxkk....oKKK00KK0OkxdolodkOO000OOkxddk00koddxkl.....................
dd,;coddxx'.....oxxddollodxkkOOOOOOOOOkkxddk000loO0d......................
::ldxxooodd,...;kxxxkkkkkkkkkkkOOOOOOOko:'...'oloxKo......................
olcldOOxolloo;,kkOOOkkkkkkkkkkkkOOko;.      .. ,cdkx;.....................
l:ccl:odOkdccloxkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkxc.      ..'',;.''odOd:....................
dxl::::;clkkxlccodxxkkkkxxxxd:.  .':ldxkxdddxkOl.;dxld,...................
odddl:;;;;:cxkkdlcloddddol:,';coxxxkkkkxxdddxkOdllxkoll...................
clooddc;;;;;;okkkxdllloodddddxxxxxxkkkkxxdodxkkkllkOkk:...................
:cclloddc:,oxxxxdddoodddddddddxxxxxkkkxxxdoodxkOooxxkk:...................
;;:cclloodoollllloodddddoodddddddxxxxxxxdooldxkOoOxddxxc..................
.',;::ccccccccllloooddddddoooooodddxxxxo:,'',;:ddkdooodd:.................
  .',;;::cccllllllooooooodddoooooodddo;..   ...'okollllod.................
   .,':::ccclllllllloooooooodollooooo;.   . ....cxlcclllo;................
```

Or you can use `--background=light` if you have a light background in your terminal:

```
~$ jp2a 1Fy7Yz2.jpg --background=light

K:.....l0000K:........'''',,,;;;;::ccccccllc::;;;,'..,0000000KKKKKKKKKKKKK
O......00O00Kc.........''''',,;;;:::cccccllc:;;;;,'..'0000000KKKKKKKKKKKKK
:.....kK000O0d............'''',,;;;::::ccccc;;;;,''..'O000000KKKKKKKKKKKKK
.....KMNXXXXXX00OOkkkkkxxxxxxxxxxxkkkOOOOO0OOOO0000OOxxKKKK0KKKKKKKKKKKKKK
'.'.cKK0KKXXXXXXXNNNWWWWWWWWWMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMWNNNNNXXKOl0KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
...,,,;;;:cld0MMWW0kdxxKKXKXNNWWWWMMMMMXNNWK0XWXNNNKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
:...,,'......,KMW0:'...,lccox00XNKWNKOdddoocc:x0X0NokKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
0Xc',:;.......;XWNkkc:0lO;:lKWNOdl:,,,,;;:;'...cXNNooKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
KNd,;c:,..'x...,kWNNOlkkKxxoc,..'',;;;,,;;;,..,,,dkk,0KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
0Xl;:cc,,'lXO'..':xkxoc;'....',:cc:,''',;::,..,c:';:,0KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
lcl:oo:;,,0KX0c........',;:clc:,''...'',;::,..,c::;,lKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
::kxoc::;;OKXXK0c;;::cllc:;,,''''''''',,;::,...lc'.:KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
ddl:;;ccc::kKKXx,;;;,,,,,,,,,,,''''''',cdOKKKOclc;.cKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKXXXXXX
clol:'';cllccxk,,''',,,,,,,,,,,,'',cx0NWMWNNX0Wko:,;xKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
ldooldc:',:oolc;,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,;o0WNNNNNX0OOkxKOOc:':dKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
:;lddddxol,,;looc:;;,,,,;;;;:d0NNKOdl:;,;:::;,'lKx:;l:kKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
c:::ldxxxxdo;,,:lolc::::cldkOxoc;;;,,,,;;:::;,':ll;,cll00KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
olcc::oxxxxxxc,,,;:lllcc:::::;;;;;;,,,,;;:c:;,,,ll,',,d00KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
doollc::odkc;;;;:::cc:::::::::;;;;;,,,;;;:cc:;,'cc;;,,dKKKKKKKXXXXXKKKKKKK
xxdoollcc:cclllllcc:::::cc:::::::;;;;;;;:ccl:;,'c';::;;oKKKXXXXXXXXXKKKKKK
0Okxddoooooooolllccc::::::cccccc:::;;;;cdkOOkxd::,:ccc::dXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
WW0Okxxddooollllllccccccc:::cccccc:::cxXXNNNXK0Oc,cllllc:0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
NWWKkOdddooollllllllcccccccc:cllcccccxKWNWKWX0K0o;loolllcxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Here's what it would look like in a terminal window:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: storm trooper? it seems inverted if so.

Comment: @Baldrickk maybe it's designed for white text on a black background?

Comment: @Baldrickk You are right, indeed it is a stormtrooper and yes, it does look better with white text on a black background.  I was too lazy to take a screenshot.  Maybe today when I am at the computer I wrote this answer on I will get a screenshot of it added.  =)

Comment: I like the `--background=light` version for display on the site :)

Answer (score 2):

Shameless plug here, but you can use my cli tool `ascii-image-converter`. It's available on snap:

```
sudo snap install ascii-image-converter
```

Or you can visit the repo if you directly want the binaries or something: https://github.com/TheZoraiz/ascii-image-converter#installation

Unlike `jp2a`, this tool supports jpeg, png, webp, bmp and tiff image formats so it'll work on most images you encounter. You can customize the output with a bunch of flags. There's also an option to directly save the ascii art as a png, to save you the hassle of taking screenshots. More documentation is available on the repo link above.

It's still relatively immature as command-line tools go and doesn't have a sea of flags and options, but I'm working on improving it and integrating new features. Give it a try! :)